# Can a US citizen work remotely for a US company while in Japan as a dependent?

Tags: legal, japan, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen who's been working in Japan under a working visa. I quit my job and am considering changing my visa status to a dependent of my wife. As the market for skilled work in Japan is extremely under competitive I'm considering working for US companies remotely.

Assuming I am on a US pay role, is there any legal considerations for employment or implications to my visa if I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your spouse visa permits work, and I believe in Japan they typically do, you should be legally in the clear.  However, you may owe taxes to both countries, and you'll probably want to get professional advice on how to handle them.

Comment: Thanks. I think there's some limits on earnings and hours worked; though I might be confusing that with the dependent status for tax purposes, and not the spousal visa limitations.
And I'll be sure take the advice to consult a professional and immigration services as well to be sure before going through with it.

Comment: OP is talking about a dependent visa, which limits them to 28 hours a week (and you have to request permission to work from immigration first). If OP's wife were Japanese (and it were therefore a spouse visa), you would be correct that work is permitted.